# How can i control my android application via internet

Tags: android

I am in the process of developing an `Android` application for home automation system, one of the features is controlling lights and fans via internet(webpage).

As I'm new to this, it would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to proceed or where to start.

Should I be using a webserver on my android phone and triggering some script from web or is there an easier way.

Comment: Wow! Show me your house when the system's finished.

Comment: Definitely, I would be more than happy to show it to the stackoverflow community which is helping me so much with the project..We are working on the bluetooth part of the microcontroller .. once that is done, things are cakewalk for us..

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is exactly [GCM.](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) With GMC, you can send a message to your android
phone and according to the message you can redirect the phone to do something.

Take a look at [DEMO](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) application.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about broadcast receivers. Read here for more http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html